# How to update Mysqli table using OOPHP

Tags: php

Hello friends i need to update some table rows in my database but i get nothing no error in my php function and no update please help me to fix this.

my table called user_account and has the following columns, id, user_id which is FK of another table, account, address

This class support all functions. Dbhandler.php

```
   public function create_account($user_id, $account, $address) {


     $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE user_account set account= ?,    address= ? where user_id = ? ");

        $stmt->bind_param("iss", $user_id, $account, $address);

        $stmt->execute();

    }



**This file calls create_account function when i submit**

 <?php

include './DbHandler.php';
$db = new DbHandler();


$response = array();

 if (  isset($_POST['user_id']) &&  (isset($_POST['account']) &&     isset($_POST['address'])  )!= '') {


    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
   $account = $_POST['account'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];



  $res = $db->createProfile($user_id, $account, $address);

} 

?>
```

Comment: I believe it should be $db->createAccount instead of $db->createProfile. You have two variables for response: $response and $res, try using one only

Comment: Yes, i have changed   $db->createProfile to $db->createAccount  and $res to $response but still no change

Comment: Could you show us any output error please?

Comment: I am getting no error really

Answer (score 0):

You're sql statement is update, but you should be using an insert. I'm assuming the row doesn't exist in the table yet since the function is called createProfile/create_account?

```
Insert into user_account values ()
```

Comment: Nope, my row exist is a reason why i need to update it , user_id is 7 , in account there is 23435, in address there is kigali

Comment: I finally found why , i removed  wherever i have user_id id Dbhandler.php and in the file which calls create_account  , example on this line:  $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE user_account set account= ?,    address= ? where user_id = ? ");    i hope this where user_id=? were causi me the problem. now the problem is that update is affecting all row but me i need that update affects last inserted row

Comment: If you do that then you'll update all records in that table.

Comment: Try reordering your bind parameters, it looks like you're passing user id for the account and the account for the user id

Comment: Yes is that problem i stay with only ,it's updating all records where i need to update only last inserted id and i don't know how do that trick !

Comment: Last_insert_id. That will give you the last one. But you lost me now. There should be only one record for each user, and you should update the appropriate row using the where condition user_id=7. Are you saying multiple rows with Id 7 exist?

Comment: No i was wrong there to say the last inserted row ,but i might say appropriate row but do do it dynamically using where condition without specifying id= to s.thing . i meant multiple rows with different id and user_id . as i mentioned at the beginning user_id is a Foreign key ,where here id is a primary key auto increment

Comment: Ok try 3 different bind one for each parameter. Or probably share some more of your source code .